# Video Playing From Memory Stream

Tags: asp.net, video

I am working in asp.net c#. I want to play video from memory stream. I am encrypting and decrypting video. I am storing the decrypted video in memory stream, and want to play it, without saving. I have googled it and found number of post, but mostly the post are uncompleted or provided the link with directshow. I have also tried with directshow, but it's totally new for me and contains number of demos, that made a confusion which one to use for Memory stream.

I just want to play decrypted video data from memory stream . Please let me know what I can do, it will be more good if there is a sample available from any forums.

My decrypted code

```
public bool DecryptData(String inName, String outName, byte[] rijnKey, byte[] rijnIV)
{
   FileStream fin = null;
    FileStream fout = null;
    CryptoStream decStream = null;

    try
    {
            fin = new FileStream(inName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            //Create variables to help with read and write.

            byte[] bin = new byte[bufLen]; //This is intermediate storage for the encryption.
            long rdlen = 0; //This is the total number of bytes written.
            long totlen = fin.Length; //This is the total length of the input file.
            int len; //This is the number of bytes to be written at a time.
            RijndaelManaged rijn = new RijndaelManaged();

            //DES ds = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

            decStream = new CryptoStream(fin, rijn.CreateDecryptor(rijnKey, rijnIV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);


            //odkoduj testowy fragment

            byte[] test = new byte[testHeader.Length];
            decStream.Read(test, 0, testHeader.Length);
            string contents = new StreamReader(decStream).ReadToEnd();
            byte[] unicodes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(contents);
            MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream(unicodes);
//here I have to implement player that plays from memory stream.
}
catch
{}
}
```

Comment: You need to use DirectShow anyway :)

Comment: I don't know , how to use it? I have downloaded it and also studied it's form. But doesn't get idea , which example to use and at how at my decryptin code .Shown Above. Can you guide me.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered one question regarding encrypting and decryption of a video file but i can understand you don't want to save a physical copy of that file on client machine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58129727/9869635

But it is not possible to play a video file from memorystream (not sure about some paid third party tools)

so one way you can do it like below approach:

1: Save that file in client's "temp" folder e.g. "temp/myvideos/sample.mkv"

2: Make it hidden from properties ([How to hide file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199571/how-to-hide-file-in-c))

3: Play the video from there

4: once it is played, delete all files from that custom folder from "temp" folder (myvideos).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it today, that works for any platform... is to use Http Live Streaming and then you can either use a player that supports HLS or you can simply use the HTML5 video tag. See my updated answer below...

[Play a video without a file on disk [Java]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19702543/play-a-video-without-a-file-on-disk-java/22918443#22918443)

Comment: Why Java code while the questioner is asking in C#.